# Force visitors to get newest versions of resources (bypassing browser cache)

Tags: web-hosting, html, css, cache

How can I (force) my visitors on my website to clean their cache, and get the new updated content? I find myself sometimes linking progress on some of my projects and sending it to others for feedback, but they have to clean their cache first to see the actual changes.

I was wondering if theres something that I can do from my position to load in the new content instantly instead of loading it from their cache?

Comment: I would go for caching your files for a shorter period, so the cache will be removed automatically, and new content will be able to show up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your site is using [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) which can be adjusted using some form of [Leverage Browser Caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching) or using version strings on your files.

Below you can 3 methods: [Apache mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html), [Apache FilesMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) and versioning strings using PHP.

*Apache mod_expires.c*

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 60 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

*Apache FilesMatch*

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|swf)$">    
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, public, must-revalidate"
  </IfModule>    
</FilesMatch>
```

*Versioning*

Adding a query string to the end of the file will make the browser believe that the file is not the same and it'll re-download it.

Each time you make a edit to the a resource you need to update the query string, for example:

1. Original version: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="pro-webmasters.css">`
2. Previous version: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="pro-webmasters.css?v=0.1">`
3. Latest version: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="pro-webmasters.css?v=0.2">`

Obviously this becomes time consuming when you have multiple css files, JavaScript files and other resources, this can be made easier by using PHP variables, for example:

```
<?php $VerNumber= "0.0.2"; ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=<?php echo $VerNumber; ?>">
<script src="jquery.js?v=<?php echo $VerNumber; ?>"></script>
<img src="image.jpg?v=<?php echo $VerNumber; ?>">
```

Comment: I've created a .htaccess file on my public_html in cpanel, and copy pasted the Apache mod_expires.c code, is that fine? Should it now stop caching my sites? Thanks

Comment: Assuming your enabled the .htaccess then yes, it'll set the cache at approx 1 minute. If your using Cloudflare or another transparent proxy such as vanish then you need to purge the cache on those also.

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I enable it in cpanel? There was no file called .htaccess I just created one and put this code in it, oh yeah I changed 60secs to 2 hours

Comment: It is by default enabled in cPanel unless it has been disabled in WHM by you or your web host which is very rare for them to do so.